# Limit of $d(u_{n+1},u_n)$ for $u_n=(1-1/n)e^{i\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $E=D(0,1)\cup\{\pm i\}$ with the subspace topology from $\Bbb{C.}$

> Is it true that the sequence $$u_n=(1-1/n)e^{i\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k}$$
>
> satisfies $d_E(u_{n+1},u_n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\to} 0$ and the the limit point are $\{\pm i\}$ ?

I tried using equivalent of $H_n$ or just using that $\vert e^{i\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k}\vert=1$ to get the result but I didn't get the fact that $d_E(u_{n+1},u_n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\to} 0$.

*To add some context, it was to find a exemple such that $d(u_{n+1},u_n)$ tends to $0$ and such that the set of limit point is not connected which is true if the base space $E$ is compact *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have :

$$d(u_{n+1},u_n) = \left| \left( 1 - \frac 1 {n+1} \right) e^{i\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1 k}-\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) e^{i\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k} \right|$$

Multiplying by $e^{-i\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k}$ does not change the modulus, then :

$$d(u_{n+1},u_n) =\left| \left( 1 - \frac 1 {n+1} \right) e^{i \frac 1 {n+1}}-\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) \right|.$$

Multiplying by $e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}$ does not change the modulus as well , it yields :

$$d(u_{n+1},u_n) = \left| \left( 1 - \frac 1 {n+1} \right) e^{i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}-\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}} \right|.$$

Developping :

$$d(u_{n+1},u_n)=\left| \left( \frac {e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} n - \frac {e^{i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} {n+1} \right) + 2i \sin\left(\frac 1 {2(n+1)} \right)\right| .$$

We concentrate on the first term :

$$\left| \frac {e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} n - \frac {e^{i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} {n+1}\right|=\frac 1 {n(n+1)} \left| (n+1) {e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} - n {e^{i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}}  \right|$$

But :
$$\left| (n+1) {e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}} - n {e^{i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}}}  \right| = \left|2i n \sin \left(  \frac 1 {2(n+1)} \right) + e^{-i \frac 1 {2(n+1)}} \right| \leq \left|2i n \sin \left(  \frac 1 {2(n+1)} \right) \right|+1.$$

Putting things together :

$$d(u_{n+1},u_n) \leq  \frac 2 {n+1}  \left|  \sin \left(  \frac 1 {2(n+1)} \right) \right| + \frac 1 {n(n+1)}  + 2 \left|\sin\left(\frac 1 {2(n+1)}\right) \right|.$$

Finally using $| \sin(x)| \leq |x|$ finishes the proof.
The way you ave chosen your space $E$, the only limit points are indeed $+i$ and $-i$, since $|u_n| \to 1$ and those points being the only one of modulus $1$ in $E$.

Comment: very nice,  is it possible to modify the sequence $u_n$ is much easier way to get the same result ? Thanks!

Comment: My computation may not by optimal though. May be there exists more complicated sequences where the computation is more easy but I can not think of any.